# Install MSSQL On Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am attempting to install MsSql on Ubuntu 16.04, but when I run `sudo apt-get update` this error is thrown

> Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssqlserver-list (type)
> The list of sources could not be read.

If I run the command `lsb_release -a` I get this output

> Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
> Xenial

And I am attempting to follow this guide - which shows it should work on this version...
[SSMS on Ubuntu 16.04](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-linux-2017)

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**
If I run the command `vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssqlserver-list`

This is what is shown

```
<html><br>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<br><body bgcolor="white"><br>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center><br>
</body><br>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share with us the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssqlserver-list . As it seems, you might be having a typo on that file hence the "malformed line" error

Comment: @kioi -> see my edit, I think that is what you are after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssqlserver-list` is meant to contain a link to where the installation file will be downloaded from.

Following the link of the installation guide that you mentioned above, this command `sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list)"` is meant to serve that purpose, and when you check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, you should see the following line `deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial main` or something close to that.

To remedy your error, delete the file you mentioned above using command

> `sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssqlserver-list`

then run the `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: That got it!  Did i type a command incorrect or what could have caused this to occur?

Comment: Am not entirely sure how this might have happened, but it probably happened because of a bad link which retrieved the wrong page which looks like it was behind Nginx